# What is difference between different outlet action destination property

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

What is the difference between `destination="-1"` `destination="-2"` and `destination="some_id"` in outlet connections Xcode?

Noticed `destination="-2"` will stop action to trigger when keyboard is active

```
<connections>
<action selector="buttonAction:" destination="-2" eventType="touchUpInside" id="Pxg-Qm-GNf"/>
<action selector="buttonAction:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="Pxg-Qm-GNf"/>
<action selector="buttonAction:" destination="U6b-Vx-4bR" eventType="touchUpInside" id="rEX-6A-hK5"/>
</connections>
```

Comment: Storyboard XML is not intended to be human-readable, nor is its implementation guaranteed to be the same from one SDK version to the next

Comment: My guess is that at least one of the values means "owner".

Comment: I have managed to find -1 in my xibs and it seems it means "File owner". I have not been able to find "-2".

Comment: @jrturton agree, but there do difference for these values. how it relates to keyboard.